# MSSQL - Insert Into Select number from global count table and update the global count for each row then inserted

Tags: sql-server-2016, select, insert, bulk-insert

Not sure I've articulated that well in the title, so here goes...

I have three tables

Table1

| ID | NewNames |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | some row data |
| 11 | some more row data |

Table2

| ID | OldNames |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | my old data |
| 2 | and more data |

and

GlobalID (with a single row numeric field)

| MaxID |
| --- |
| 12 |

I'd like to use a Insert Into Select like below:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
ID
,NewNames
) SELECT 'a new id'
,OldNames FROM table2
```

'a new id' is a numeric value and should equal the (max value + 1) from the GlobalID table.

My problem is I obviously need to keep adjusting the GlobalID table and increase the max for each row as I'm inserting from the Select!

Does that make sense?

Any help appreciated. Using sql server 2016 if that makes any difference.
Les

Comment: How many rows are in `table2`? What is the data type of the `ID` column in `table1`? Is the `ID` column in `table1` supposed to be unique?

Comment: Hi JD - it's a simplified version of the real data, but the select from Table 2 will never be more than 500 rows at any one time in truth - ID is a numeric (16,0)

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining your own global max `ID` table is going to be a pain because it's at risk of incorrect results when there's concurrency (in addition to other reasons). This is why features like an [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16) or [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) exist.

You should create `Table1` with the `ID` column as an identity like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    ID NUMERIC(16,0) IDENTITY(TheStartingValue, 1), -- TheStartingValue should be larger than the max value in Table2
    NewNames NVARCHAR(1000) -- Or whatever size you need
);
```

Then any inserts from `Table2` can be simplified like so:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (NewNames) 
SELECT OldNames 
FROM table2;
```

You don't need to maintain your own global `ID` table this way. The identity will automatically populate (concurrency safe) new values for you in the table as rows are inserted into it.

Comment: Thanks JD, I suspected as much.  Unfortunately the system is not mine and I'm locked into using the globalID method - not usually a problem as my various stored procedures are only ever updating or inserting a single record in a transaction - but not in this case. :(

Comment: @Les sorry, just to confirm, you don't have control over `Table1`?

Comment: I do, and could push anything I wanted into the ID column via SQL manager and query (within reason), but it already holds many thousands of records and the proprietary software that references the table directly uses the max value method for inserting new IDs as primary key (non-computed) and I'd rather not risk affecting that.  Looking like a non-starter?

Comment: @Les "*Looking like a non-starter?*" - Not yet, still not fully following though. So does the 3rd party software insert into `Table1` or `Table2`?

Comment: Table 1 for this purpose.  Table 2 is just a construct for the example, will actually be a complex select from multiple other tables in the database that I want to use a source.  There are multiple columns in each too, but I thought I was making the example easier by giving a barebones example - sorry if this has just confused matters.

Comment: @Les Ok so I think I can imagine the rest of the gap in the problem statement. Your goal is to insert data from another source into `Table1` with `ID`s that don't overlap with the one's being generated by the 3rd party software?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly! Sorry for the struggle to articulate that LOL

Comment: @Les No worries at all. Do you care if the `ID`s of the rows that you are inserting into `Table1` from this other source, are negative numbers? This would simplify the ensurance of no collisions (assuming 3rd party software doesn't change in the future - but all bets are off then anyway). This also has the added benefit of being able to easily identify which rows came naturally from the 3rd party software and which rows did not.

Comment: Not completely comfortable with that, but only because my knowledge of potential downsides.

what if I 'reserve' the ids based on a count of rows from Table 2 e.g. declare a variable MyMin which is the current value from GlobalID table to hold starting value, a variable MyCount which is a count of the select from table 2, and a variable MyMax which would be the sum of those 2 --- set the GlobalID.MaxID value to MyMax value effectively reserving that range for the insert into?  ID is then simply MyMin + a row_number() - still a problem with concurrency?

Comment: time for home, I'll catch up tomorrow JD, thanks for everything thus far :)

Comment: "*Not completely comfortable with that, but only because my knowledge of potential downsides.*" - Care to elaborate on that? I didn't fully follow your last suggestion but loosely it sounds like it would still be at risk of collisions and concurrency issues. It'll be pretty hard to avoid those issues with an external system that manages its own ID list, without picking a set of numbers that are rather well outside the range of possibilities (e.g. negative numbers or a well buffered gap by a few orders of magnitude). "*thanks for everything thus far :)*" - Np! I'm sure we'll come to a solution.

Comment: Hi JD - back to work today :(  -- I really should have said 'lack of knowledge', meaning I wouldn't like to do something which may impact the 3rd party software

Comment: @Les Oh, well the potential downsides are minimal. I don't think any solution is possible with less potential downsides other than not touching these tables at all. Certainly less than trying to manipulate their `GlobalID` table via any of the alternatives discussed so far. Using negative numbers for the `ID`s you insert into `Table1` removes the `GlobalID` from being touched at all then.

Comment: Alternatively, do you need to touch these 3rd party tables at all or can you use your own custom table + a view to union the data together for your own consumption? That would be the least risky.